# How to setup Cocos2D-X (Android) under Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Hi I've made a small game for iPhone that I also want to run on Android but I'm having problems setting up Cocos2D-X for Android.

I've downloaded and installed Android SDK and NDK (under my `"/Users/username/Android"`).

Installed all necessary packages under SDK and created an Emulator.
Copied Cocos2D-x under `"/Users/username/cocos2dx"`.

Installed Eclipse IDE with ADT Plugin.

Opened `"Users/username/cocos2dx/tests/build_native.sh"` and changed `"NDK_ROOT_LOCAL=/Users/username/Android/android-ndk"`, `"COCOS2DX_ROOT_LOCAL=/Users/username/cocos2dx"` to the values shown.

On running the script using Terminal it compiles test project. What's next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps are as follows:

- Generate the project for Android using cocos2d-x template
- Add project to [NVPack's Eclipse](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack)
- Fix make files, IDE configuration and whatnots
- Compile the libraries with Cygwin and build_native.sh script, they will be automatically added to the obj folder of the project
- Execute/debug like an Android application

Those are the windows steps, I am not sure about the iOs part but it shouldn't be much different.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial on creating a Cocos2d-X [meta-project](http://paralaxer.com/cocos2d-x-project-setup/) for multiple platforms.